# VBA: focus of selection after SelectAll

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VBA code that opens a workbook.  It then does the following:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Shapes.SelectAll
Selection.Delete
```

I thought after the SelectAll,  the Selection should be the shapes just being selected, which are what I want to delete. No. It's not. It's the active cell in the just-opened workbook and it's that active cell that's deleted. Usually, Selection after Select refers to the objects just being selected. Apparently, in the case of SelectAll, that's not true. How to set the focus to the just-selected shapes?

I changed my approach by doing SelectAll then assigned the selected shapes to a shaperange object following the method in [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.shapes.selectall). The method is in the following:

```
Set myDocument = Worksheets(1) 
myDocument.Shapes.SelectAll

Set sr = Selection.ShapeRange
```

My code is:

```
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Shapes.SelectAll
    Set sr = Selection.ShapeRange
```

Unfortunately, that document doesn't say what the sr is declared to. I have declared it as a shape, shapes, ShapeRange, Object, Variant. In every case, Excel complained "Object doesn't support this property or method." I wonder what it's set to in the MS document.

I know I can delete all shapes using a For loop but I'm trying to avoid doing a loop.

Comment: I have no problem with those lines. selectAll selects all the shapes on that sheet. It selects all shapes and you then delete them. Also, the documentation does indicate the type which is Dim sr as ShapeRange. See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.shaperange). Check what type the shapes are because I was surprised that when I added a triangle and a square and selected then I needed _Dim sr As DrawingObjects: Set sr = Selection: sr.Delete_

Comment: I have photos and textboxes and your method works. Thanks. The link you gave contains a long list of Excel objects. I thought it an exhaustive list but no. Drawingobjects is not listed in it.

Answer (score 2):

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Shapes.SelectAll
Selection.Delete
```

is fundamentally wrong because it attempts to convert a *Shapes Collection* into a *Selection object*.

The Selection object exists entirely and almost exclusively for the use and benefit of the user: the user may select something to show to VBA or VBA may select something to show to the user. In your example the user is excluded from the process. Therefore involvement of the *Selection* object is a waste of time and resources. You wouldn't have to ask your question if you weren't trying to make something work that isn't designed to work in that way.

The correct approach is to identify the object and do with it whatever you want. The object is either the collection of all shapes on the worksheet (`ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Shapes`) or any member of it, such as `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Shapes(1)`. You also have `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Shapes.Count` at your disposal to loop through them all or `For Each Shp in ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Shapes`.

The `ShapeRange` object contains another collection. It's name promises a smaller collection than all shapes on the sheet. Don't let the choice of collections confuse you. The job is to identify one or several shapes and delete them. The fact of the matter is that you do have to deal with a member of a collection and not the *Selection* object.

Comment: Thanks for the answerr. ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Shapes doesn' t have a Delete method. How does one delete all shapes?

Comment: Delete them one by one, in a loop.

Comment: That's the method I used. I wanted to avoid the loop. Thus, I started to experiment with different methods. Please see QHarr's comment above, right below my question. That method works without involving loop. Strange. After SeletAll, I could set sr=Selection and then delete it by doing sr.Delete while direct Selection.Delete did not work.

Comment: QHarr showed you how to assign a ShapeRange to the Selection object. I told you the Selection object shouldn't be used. I don't think these are opposing or incompatible ideas. You may or may not have saved one line of code. Your code may or may not run equally fast. Bottom line is that you have unorthodox code which will be harder to maintain forever. Whoever looks at your code in the future will wonder why the Selection object was chosen in that instance. It's like using a potato peeler to skin an onion. It can be done.